# Formatting commas in URLSession parameters in Swift

Tags: swift, url, networking

I need to make this request to the Spotify API (https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-audio-features-several-tracks/)

It takes track IDs separated with commas as a parameter like this: ids=111111%2C222222%2C3333

```
let url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features"
let parameters = ["ids": "111%2C222%2C333"]
let headers = ["Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer TOKEN"]

var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: url)
var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value))
    }
    urlComponents?.queryItems = queryItems
    var request = URLRequest(url: (urlComponents?.url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    for (key, value) in headers {
        request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
    }
```

But when I use the %2C as a separator in the parameters, the urlComponents does some stuff and I end up with 111%252C222%252C333 as a parameter in my URL.

Comment: I think you can just use this `let parameters = ["ids": "111,222,333"]` and it should work

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot. I can't believe I didn't try to just use normal commas in the URL...

Answer (score 0):

%25 is the url encoding for the '%' sign https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP, so it's encoding your '%' sign in the '%2C'